# Why git-revert doesn't invoke the pre-commit and the commit-msg hooks?

Tags: git

Using strace I noticed that git-revert invokes only two hooks:

- prepare-commit-msg
- post-commit

But git-commit invoke these four:

- pre-commit
- prepare-commit-msg
- commit-msg
- post-commit

Since git-revert produces a commit, why doesn't it invoke the same
hooks as git-commit?

I asked this on the Git mailing list but got no response. So I'm asking here.

I ended up researching this when I was implementing a hook to detect
and deny commits which revert merge-commits, since they are
[troublesome](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.html).

I tried to implement it as a commit-msg hook to search for the string
"This reverts commit SHA-1" in the commit message. But git-revert
doesn't invoke the commit-msg hook.

So, for now I implemented my check as a pre-receive hook. But I find
it useful to have all pre-receive checks implemented also as a
pre-commit or a commit-msg hook so that I can detect problems at
commit time instead of only at push time.

Comment: Just to be clear, is the issue that the revert commit is not triggering a client side hook, or a server side hook?  I would think that you could create a server side hook which could detect such a commit and then block it.  But +1 to a great question.

Comment: The issue is that the command git-revert doesn't invoke all client side hooks that the command git-commit invokes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The sequencer code actually runs `git commit` to produce the commit](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a4ee44448fe98dcd8f1db9e43729ac67fc80e031/sequencer.c#L677-L751).  But this code (see link above) contains the fragment:

```
    if (!(flags & VERIFY_MSG))
            argv_array_push(&cmd.args, "-n");
```

which means it runs `git commit -n` by default.  The `-n` flag:

> bypasses the pre-commit and commit-msg hooks

as noted in [the `git commit` documentation.](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-commit.html)  The things that set `VERIFY_MSG` are interactive rebase "edit" or "reword" and the like, but not `git cherry-pick`.

<s>Note that once the sequencer is done, it will invoke your post-rewrite hook (if you have one), so you should put your check there instead.</s> As you note, you can specifically edit the commit message, and if you do so, it seems like your commit messge hook *ought* to be used, but it isn't.

Comment: Your lead allowed me to find why the git-commit is being invoked with the -n flag by git-revert. It happened on commit 9fa4db544e2e, by Junio Hamano, in 2005! I got it, but since you can edit the commit message in a git-revert, I think there's a case to be made to make the pre-commit and the commit-msg being invoked by default.

Anyways, I'll bring this discussion to Git's mailing list.

However, I checked and git-revert doesn't invoke the post-rewrite hook. Even if it did, since it's a "post" hook it wouldn't be able to abort the command.

But you answered my question. Thanks!

Comment: Oops, right, the post-rewrite hook invocation is only if the sequencer is being used for `git rebase -i`.