# Commit-msg hook not triggered for git revert

Tags: git, hook

When doing a git revert , a commit message editor is shown with the default message "Revert 'originalMsg'". I want to trigger a hook after the user edits the default revert message. However it seems that git revert triggers only the pre-commit-msg and post-commit hooks, as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48852925/why-git-revert-doesnt-invoke-the-pre-commit-and-the-commit-msg-hooks).

For me, it is too early to put the message check hook in pre-commit-msg, I need to trigger the hook after the commit editor is closed and the user saved the new message.

```
steps:
1. git revert commit_id
2. pre-commit-msg hook is triggered >>> **too early to put here my checks**
3. editor commit msg
4. close editor msg >> **after close I need to triger check-msg HOOK**
5. post-commit hook is triggered
```

Comment: In post-commit the commit is already done. Hook is triggered but even if the mesage syntax fails, the commit is still done.

Comment: For `git-commit` or `git-merge`, you can check the commit message after editing and saving the file that holds the commit message and before committing is done in the hook `commit-msg`. However `commit-msg` is not invoked by `git-revert`, unless you use `git revert -n <commit> && git commit`.